# Set SQL column in table A based on column in table B

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I just can't quite get this syntax correct.  Table 'clients' has a points_per_month column.  Table 'usage' has an 'available' column and a 'client_id' column.  I basically want to rewrite the available value to match the points_per_month value.  I tried this:

```
update usage
set available = c.points_per_month
from usage u
inner join clients c on u.client_id = c.ident;
```

But that's setting all of the available values to the exact same number (the points_per_month of the first client returned)

Comment: I would try to remove the alias `u`. Maybe the database uses `usage` and `u` as two different copies of the table. I. e. `... from usage
inner join clients c on usage.client_id = c.ident`.

Comment: > update usage set available = c.points_per_month from usage inner join clients c on usage.client_id = c.ident;
ERROR:  table name "usage" specified more than once

Comment: @Gargoyle Error message tells you the exact cause of error `table name "usage" specified more than once`. You do not need to repeat a table in `from` if it is already in `update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
update usage u
set available = c.points_per_month
from clients c 
where u.client_id = c.ident;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  It won't let me accept your answer for another 5 minutes....

Answer (score 0):

The classic way with a subselect as assignment should work for every database:

```
update usage
set available = (select c.points_per_month
                   from clients c
                  where usage.client_id = c.ident
);
```